# Перехват исключения (стоит ли) C#

Tags: c#, исключения

Мне кажется код немного кривоват, но не могу понять как лучше его переделать.
Код:

```
void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
    {
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(openFileDialog1.FileName))
        {
            throw new PathException("Некорректный путь к файлу", openFileDialog1.FileName);
        }
        try
        {
            textBox7.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
        catch (PathException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}: {1}", ex.Message, ex.PathValue), "Ошибка.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }
    }       
}
```

Класс исключения:

```
public class PathException : ArgumentException
{   
    public string PathValue {get; set;}
    public PathException(string message, string pathValue)
        :base(message)
    {
        PathValue = pathValue;
    }
}
```

Что можно исправить?

Comment: Вы же не ловите то исключение, которое бросили. И в этом случае - точно не стоит использовать исключения. Достаточно обычного if.

Comment: Такая себе идея нумеровать textBoxы, фиг потом разберешься какой за что отвечает.

Comment: А их никто и не нумерует, если добавляешь их через интерфейс среды.

Comment: Добавил через интерфейс среды и сразу же дал нормальное название. И текстбоксам, и кнопкам, и всем остальным компонентам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я предполагаю, что вы хотели поместить начало блока try до if (в текущем виде код не имеет смысла).

Большинство методов работы с файлами в .NET автоматически бросают исключение, если файла не существует, так что вам может и не нужна такая проверка в явном виде. У OpenFileDialog по умолчанию есть предупреждение при выборе несуществующего файла. Но так или иначе, нет смысла бросать исключение только из-за того, что пользователь ввел несуществующий файл. Проброс исключений - довольно тяжелая операция, которая предназначена для действительно исключительных ситуаций. Вы могли бы сделать так:

```
if (!System.IO.File.Exists(openFileDialog1.FileName))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Некорректный путь к файлу " + openFileDialog1.FileName);
    return;
}
```

Если вы все же бросаете исключения, нет смысла ловить их тут же только для того, чтобы вывести сообщение. Польза исключений отчасти в том, чтобы захватить стек вызовов для облегчения отладки сложного кода. При таком коде эти данные теряются.

Обычная практика относительно исключений это одно из двух:

- Просто позволить программе упасть. В этом случае выведется сообщение и диагностическая информация попадет в системный журнал
- Перехватить исключение и вывести сообщение, но при этом логировать с помощью собственного механизма его полные данные (`ex.ToString()`)